# What's the chronological order of the flashback episodes?

Tags: suggested-order, person-of-interest

Occasionally *Person of Interest* has episodes that flashback to before the start of the series.  These episodes focus on various elements of The Machine and friend's origins and history.  They're spread out over the seasons, which makes keeping track of them a bit messy.  I'd like to rewatch them in the in-universe chronological order though.

What order are the flashback episodes of *Person of Interest* in, chronologically?

It'd be especially helpful to include a short description for what story or element each flashback deals with.

Answer (score 3):

A link to a youtube video with all the flashbacks in chronological order.

Fair warning: 3hr+

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Thanks for the warning about the extended video, but could you possibly summarise the events?  This would greatly improve your answer's quality!

Comment: This probably answers the question, but unless you write a summary of the contents of the video, this answer will be deleted as "Link Only".  You need to explain the answer, not merely post a video that explains it.